# Get RGB color values on OpenCV and C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, opencv, emgucv

I can't find a solution to a simple problem I have:

In this code:

```
private void ibOriginal_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int mouse_get_X = (int)(e.Location.X);
    int mouse_get_Y = (int)(e.Location.Y);

    Byte byte_color = imgOriginal.Data[mouse_get_X, mouse_get_Y, 0];
}
```

I want to have an RGB value (in a 3-dimensional array of int) of a pixel with X,Y coordinates get by a Mouse Click.

Can I make a conversion of "byte_color"? 
Is it correct?

I can't find anything in C# that can help me, I'm using EmguCV.

Comment: It's possible to get RGB into a byte, with 2 bpp, What type is the imgOriginal.Data?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'll probably want to have:

```
imgOriginal.Data[mouse_get_Y, mouse_get_X, 0];  //note X and Y swapped
```

Secondly, in OpenCV data is stored in bands which you choose with the last index. Their interpretation depends on your image type. If you have [BGR](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.3.0.0/html/f6682fa1-90bf-e2b0-50d5-084e3e8d1307.htm) image type for example, then:

```
imgOriginal.Data[mouse_get_Y, mouse_get_X, 0]; // blue
imgOriginal.Data[mouse_get_Y, mouse_get_X, 1]; // green
imgOriginal.Data[mouse_get_Y, mouse_get_X, 2]; // red
```

Similarly to other image types defined in this namespace: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.3.0.0/html/b72c032d-59ae-c36f-5e00-12f8d621dfb8.htm

When bands have `byte` resolution they have values from range 0...255, so basically you have an integer already, and you can put it into a text box easily:

```
textBox.Text = byteValue.ToString();
```

Comment: Ok, i solved adding this line of code: imgOriginal = imgOriginal.Convert<Bgr, byte>();